# How to change keyboard layout in i3?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, i3-window-manager

I am using 'i3` window manager on Fedora 25.
I've already uninstalled GNOME Desktop. I want to change keyboard layout and set it to languages other than English, and desirably also to set it as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut for easy access.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use setxkbmap:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,de
setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
```

Just change the keyboard layouts us,de to what ever you prefer.
If you want i3 to run these commands on startup, just add them to your config file "~/.i3/config" and prepend "exec".

```
exec "setxkbmap -layout us,de"
exec "setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'"
```

Checkout http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:window_managers:keyboard_layout_in_i3

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to add an indication of it on i3bar as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. See http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:window_managers:keyboard_layout_in_i3#displaying_the_active_layout_in_the_panel

Comment: this just doesn't work, nothing changes when using alt-shift =(

Comment: Have you tried using the setxkbmap commands from the command line (without the i3 config)? What does it say when you run `setxkbmap -query`?

Comment: It is important to add these lines into config in it's top, otherwise come short keys might be broken

Comment: I'm not seeing in the documentation where if any the language codes are specified. Is there a list? I don't see where the Windows key is specified either. Is there a way to specify a toggle using it?

Comment: Maybe you can find the possible options of setxkbmap in "/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst". On my system, for example, there's a line in that file for "grp:win_space_toggle" which you could use to use the windows key. More options are listed there. In the same file you might also find the available language codes (search for the line "! layout").

Comment: Language 2 letter codes are at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` . It may be different from windows/web 2 letter codes

Comment: Beware that due to a bug, if you use Alt+Shift to swtich, all other shortcuts containing this sequence would be disabled (like tty mode shortcut). https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/258

Comment: thank you! how can I make an indicator in my status bar?

Comment: `setxkbmap -option 'grp:win_space_toggle'` for toggling with `Super+Space`.

Comment: Add `--no-startup-id` to the `exec` if you get a spinning mouse cursor during startup.

Answer (score 11):

For me only the following worked in Manjaro + i3:

```
exec_always "setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru,ua -variant ,, -option grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

I specified this in     ~/.config/i3/config file

Comment: Be sure to find out which ```-model``` you got by running ```setxbmap -query``` in your terminal prior. Mine turned out to be ```pc105```. Worked for me.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me as of 2023 October, Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar release). Keep in mind @rtviii comment as it won't work if the `-model` flag is incorrectly set.

Answer (score 10):

It indeed seems that everything must be written inside a single command in the i3 config file in order for setxkbmap to work as desired, at least on Arch linux.

Example: English + Czech qwerty keyboard, ALT+SHIFT toggle:

```
exec "setxkbmap -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle' -layout us,cz -variant ,qwerty"
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired shortcut set by XKB option `grp:alt_shift_toggle`

---

But using `setxkbmap -option` in *~/.i3/config* for configuring keyboard layouts is not the best approach.

- **Bluetooth** keyboards can go to **sleep** to save battery then reconnect. In that case layout configuration will be **reset** to default.
- There is no way to configure keyboards **separate**. For example, my Bluetooth keyboard has no **Right Alt** so I am using **Caps Lock** on it.

If this is your case consider using */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf* (`man xorg.conf` DESCRIPTION for all available paths):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:toggle"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Bluetooth Keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchProduct "Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:caps"
EndSection
```

---

See `man xkeyboard-config`

- LAYOUTS for language codes in `XkbLayout`
- OPTIONS for switching to another layout hotkeys (all `grp:*`)

Or:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45499/384576

---

See `xinput list` for `MatchProduct`

More:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220082/384576

Answer (score 1):

insert into your .config/i3/config

```
# switch keymap

bindsym $mod+Ctrl+Shift+F11 exec setxkbmap -layout ch -variant fr
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+Shift+F12 exec setxkbmap -layout ru -variant phonetic
```

Answer (score 0):

"exec setxkbmap" didn't work for me. Through frustrated keyboard smashing, I accidentally pulled up the display settings (Super+D since I installed from Regolith-desktop), and from there I could open up "Region & Language" to set the keyboard layout. I guess i3 "Ubuntu" keyboard layout settings are store separate from "Kubuntu" keyboard layout settings.

Answer (score 0):

my setup:
*gnome manjaro + i3 default* 
**1 step  - cd ~/.config/i3/ and edit config** (example vi or nvim confif)
**2 step past this line** `exec_always "setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru,ua -variant ,, -option grp:alt_shift_toggle"`  if you need to change language

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).